# Global variable's value lost between function calls in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I know I must have missed something basic -- just want to make sure I get the precise answer.

I have the following code. Why `CACHE_KEYS` is still None after `load()` while `CACHE` is not?

```
import bisect
import csv

DB_FILE = "GeoLiteCity-Location.csv"

# ['locId', 'country', 'region', 'city', 'postalCode', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'metroCode', 'areaCode']
CACHE = []
CACHE_KEYS = None


def load():
    R = csv.reader(open(DB_FILE))

    for line in R:
        CACHE.append(line)

    # sort by city
    CACHE.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])

    CACHE_KEYS = [x[3] for x in CACHE]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load()

    # test
    # print get_geo("Ruther Glen")
```

Comment: Thanks for all answers. I got the idea. Instead of using `global` I'm more comfortable w/ `CACHE_KEYS.extend([x[3] for x in CACHE])` and making `CACHE_KEYS` a list in the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think making it `global` would work. Any variable defined in the global scope which is to be edited should be specified as `global` in that function. Your code just makes a local variable `CACHE_KEYS` and stores the information correctly. But, to make sure that it is copied to the global variable, declare the variable as `global` in the function.  You call the `append` function on `CACHE` and hence that works fine. Your code after the changes.

```
import bisect
import csv

DB_FILE = "GeoLiteCity-Location.csv"

# ['locId', 'country', 'region', 'city', 'postalCode', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'metroCode', 'areaCode']
CACHE = []
CACHE_KEYS = None


def load():
    R = csv.reader(open(DB_FILE))

    for line in R:
        CACHE.append(line)

    # sort by city
    CACHE.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
    global CACHE_KEYS
    CACHE_KEYS = [x[3] for x in CACHE]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load()
```

Anytime you assign a value to a global variable you have to declare it as `global`. See the following code snippet.

```
listOne = []
def load():
    listOne+=[2]
if __name__=="__main__":
    load()
```

The above code has an assignment and not an `append` call. This gives the following error.

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'listOne' referenced before assignment
```

But, executing the following snippet.

```
listOne = []
def load():
    listOne.append(2)
if __name__=="__main__":
    load()
```

gives the following output.

```
>>> print listOne
[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is in

```
CACHE_KEYS = [x[3] for x in CACHE]
```

`CACHE_KEYS` is defined in the global scope. In the above line, you are assigning it a new value, bringing it into the local scope, In order to manipulate the variable in a function (and keep it's value later), `global` it :

```
def load():
    global CACHE_KEYS
    ...
    CACHE.sort(key=lambda x: x[3])
    CACHE_KEYS = [x[3] for x in CACHE]
```